# Javac not recognized after setting path to JDK/bin directory

Tags: java, environment-variables

Javac worked perfectly fine before. Now it's suddenly not recognized as an internal or external command. 
I've reset the path to the JDK/bin directory and restarted Command Prompt, but that hasn't helped.
I've also restarted my computer, after which it worked once, but then it quit on me again.
I'm using Java version 1.8.0_031.

Edit - path variable is as follows:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance
>   Toolkit\;"C:\Users\inkeye\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin";C:\Users\inkeye\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

Comment: show your path variable. echo $PATH on Unix, echo %PATH% on windows

Comment: @shazin - I've added my path variable.

Comment: On your System Variables, try create variable name `JAVA_HOME` and fill it with `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`. Don't forget to open new command line to test it.

Comment: @Sukma Wardana - I've done this. I'm confused however, as my default path and JAVA_HOME both give the exact same path variable.

Comment: It's different actually, on your PATH you're including until `bin` dir, but on your **JAVA_HOME** it's not included `bin` path, but is that works?

Comment: No, I've set the path to JAVA_HOME, but unfortunately javac is still not recognized. I've compared the path variables both before and after setting the path to JAVA_HOME using .equals and this indicates they're identical.

Comment: @swampbrain could try to put C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin at the first position into Path enviroment variable and  JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131